# How can I make SASS editing work in Chrome Devtools?

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools

I just follow [this tutplus tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools--net-32805) for source map sass.

I cannot find **Support for sass** option in **Experiment** tab under the inspect element in chrome. Is it removed? Am I late to use this feature ?

My sass version is 3.3.8 (Maptastic Maple)

How can I make SASS editing work in Chrome Devtools?

Comment: You do realize that article is a year old, right?  It probably isn't considered experimental anymore.

Comment: Yes its old. I can't use them. Its bad for me.

Comment: Is there any new and updated tutorials I can follow to make it work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made it work. SASS support is no longer an experiment: It's now a standard. 
I just follow simple steps to make it work.

1) Open your **inspect element** on chrome and click on **gear icon** which appears to the top right.

2) Enable the **CSS source maps** (which is I think its enabled by default. If not just check it. After enable the css source map don't close it.)

3) Click on **Workspace** tab on the left panel just below the General tab.

4) Add your source code folder by clicking the **Add folder** button (close the box.)

5) Go on **Sources** tab and find your scss file.

Now you can make changes and hit ctrl+s it will automatically change on your style.scss.

Comment: this only works when you change scss file code directly, right? when i make changes in `elements -> styles` tab, it will only change the `.css` compiled file, and it can't save the changes to the `.scss` file. but when i edit the `.scss` file directly (in chrome code editor), it can save that. is it same for you? isn't there any way to save the changes (in `elements -> style tab`) to `scss` source file?

Answer (score 4):

As of Chrome 75, here's how you turn on CSS source maps.

1. Open the browser's Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).
2. Open the dropdown menu in the top right corner, and click on "Settings."
   [image]
3. Look for the checkbox that reads "Enable CSS source maps" and turn it on.
   [image]

Comment: The other answer has steps missing here

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents here. Kaspersky Chome extension was blocking my CSS mapping on Chrome Developer Tools. Didn't find anywhere how to add an exception to that...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29875276)

Comment: How so? I was having this issue and found out that what was making this solution it NOT work was the Kaspersky Chrome Extension. I wish someone did make this comment so I could have helped me find out what the problem was.