# I can't get SASS support in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sass

I have some web pages.I want to view the sass files in google chrome.I have followed the steps in this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools--net-32805
But always when I go to Settings->Experiments,I can't get the "Support for Sass" field.
Did I miss any step??
thanks for help

NB:I have attached to my Experiments Tab in chrome

[image]

Comment: any help please :(

Comment: Hi again,I just still need help please to read the scss files in chrome any help plz thanks

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351306/how-can-i-make-sass-editing-work-in-chrome-devtools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make SASS editing work in Chrome Devtools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351306/how-can-i-make-sass-editing-work-in-chrome-devtools)